# pyreadstat encoding latin1 to read SAS Datasets not working?

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, sas

I have a sas dataset with Latin-1 encoding as follows:
[image]

I am trying to read this using pyreadstat with encoding specified as Latin1 with a failure message as follows:
[image]

Any inputs as to why this is happening and any workaround would be highly appreciated!

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the encoding, it is coming from a change in Readstat (the C library behind pyreadstat) where they admit files with versions being only numeric, while some files have letters on it ( V for viya or visual). Versions of pyreadstat prior to 0.3 would work.

The issue is tracked [here](https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat/issues/117) in pyreadstat and [here](https://github.com/WizardMac/ReadStat/issues/232).

Once the issue is repaired in Readstat, it will be fixed in Pyreadstat.

Comment: Thanks Otto. Very responsive and much appreciated.